# DRF post request multiple inner serializers

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

i have three models named Smoker,Switch,Survey i have smoker as foreign key in Switch model and switch as foreign key in Survey model

```
class Smoker(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    mobile = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    gender = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    age = models.ForeignKey(Age,models.DO_NOTHING,blank=True, null=True)
    occupation = models.ForeignKey(Occupation, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

class Switch(models.Model):
    time = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    count_outers = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    count_packs = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    smoker = models.ForeignKey(Smoker, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    new_brand = models.ForeignKey(NewBrand, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    new_sku = models.ForeignKey(NewSku, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

    # def __str__(self):
    #     return self.time.strftime("%H:%M")


class Survey(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    bool_switch = models.BooleanField(null=True, blank=True)
    reason = models.ForeignKey(Reason, models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)
    shift = models.ForeignKey(ShiftingTime, models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)
    current_brand = models.ForeignKey(CurrentBrand, models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)
    current_sku = models.ForeignKey(CurrentSku, models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)
    pos = models.ForeignKey(Pos, models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)
    switch = models.ForeignKey(Switch, models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, blank=True)
```

and here i have my serializers:

```
class SmokerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Smoker
        fields = '__all__'

class SwitchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    smoker = SmokerSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Switch
        fields = '__all__'
        def create(self, validated_data):
           smoker_data = validated_data.pop('smoker', None)
           if smoker_data:
             smoker = Smoker.objects.create(**smoker_data)
             validated_data['smoker'] = smoker
           return Switch.objects.create(**validated_data)

class SurveySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    switch = SwitchSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Survey
        fields = '__all__'
    def create(self, validated_data):

        switch_data = validated_data.pop('switch', None)
        if switch_data:
            switch = Switch.objects.create(**switch_data)
            validated_data['switch'] = switch
        return Survey.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

and i make a generic for for Creating and listing all the survey

```
class SurveyCreateAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Survey.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SurveySerializer
```

for each displayed survey i have to display switch data related to it and inside the switch object i need to display the smoker object inside it so each survey object must look like this

```
{
        "id": 11,
        "switch": {
            "id": 12,
            "smoker": {
               "firstname":"sami",
               "lastname:"hamad",
               "mobile":"7983832",
               "gender":"0",
               "age":"2",
               "occupation":"2"
          },
            "time": null,
            "count_outers": 5,
            "count_packs": 7,
            "new_brand": 2,
            "new_sku": 2
        },
        "date": "2018-12-08",
        "bool_switch": true,
        "user": 7,
        "reason": 3,
        "shift": 2,
        "current_brand": 6,
        "current_sku": 4,
        "pos": 2
    },
```

but when i make a POST request it is giving me this error

> ValueError at /api/v2/surveysync/ Cannot assign
>   "OrderedDict([('first_name', 'aline'), ('last_name', 'youssef'),
>   ('mobile', 7488483), ('gender', False), ('age', ),
>   ('occupation', )])": "Switch.smoker" must be
>   a "Smoker" instance.

so please help and thank you so much!

Comment: There is no return statement from your switchSerializer create method?

Comment: @c6754 i added it and same error

Comment: In your code is the create method on the serializer or on the Meta class?

Comment: i do not define a create method for it

Comment: ? In SwitchSerializer you defined a create method on the Meta class, not the serialized class itself.

Comment: i need a correct answer brother if you can make a clear answer please

Comment: @AndrehAbboud have you checked my answer below? did it help?

Comment: @Ken4scholars yes checked it but it gives me You must call .is_valid() before calling .save()

Answer (score 1):

You're going along the right path but you're saving the switch objects manually instead of allowing the `SwitchSerializer` do it for you. Same thing with create method in switch serializer. It should be this way:

```
class SmokerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Smoker
        fields = '__all__'

class SwitchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    smoker = SmokerSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Switch
        fields = '__all__'
    def create(self, validated_data):
       smoker_data = validated_data.pop('smoker', None)
       if smoker_data:
         serializer = SmokerSerializer(data=smoker_data, context=self.context)
         if serializer.is_valid():    
            validated_data['smoker'] = serializer.save()
       return super().create(validated_data)

class SurveySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    switch = SwitchSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Survey
        fields = '__all__'
    def create(self, validated_data):

        switch_data = validated_data.pop('switch', None)
        if switch_data:
            serializer = SwitchSerializer(data=switch_data, context=self.context)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                validated_data['switch'] = serializer.save()
        return super().create(validated_data)
```

Comment: it is giving me You must call `.is_valid()` before calling `.save()`.

Comment: @AndrehAbboud I've updated my answer to take care of that

Comment: @AndrehAbboud I forgot to remove one of the save methods. Done that. It's difficult to debug myself since I'm just writing it but not running it

Comment: look man the insert is working but it is adding the switch null {
        "id": 13,
        "switch": null,
        "date": "2018-12-10",
        "bool_switch": true,
        "user": 4,
        "reason": 3,
        "shift": 2,
        "current_brand": 5,
        "current_sku": 5,
        "pos": 2
    } and the switch contains the smoker object

Comment: That is what I tried to explain in my answer. You are trying to create a switch using json of a smoker instead of the smoker object. Do you realize that in your code the create method of switchserializer is never getting called? that's what I corrected in my answer.

Comment: so what can you please give me the answer to get the json object that i want ....inside the survey create the switch object and for the switch create a smoker so what to do ?

Comment: do i need to write everything in the create function of the Survey serializer ?

Comment: That is exactly what I have done. You should know that people who answer here don't run the code, so you don't expect it to work 100% without bugs. I've fixed the error you mentioned. If it still doesn't work post the error here

Comment: the error is that it is creating the survey object but the switch is null

Comment: @AndrehAbboud I'm sorry I can't help if you fail to read what I'm typing. I already wrote in my previous comments why that is happening and how I tried to solve it in the answer I gave. if you don't want to try that then it's your choice

Comment: Why run the serializer again within the `create` method? Even the drf docs suggest that you just create the instance manually in this situation.

Comment: @c6754 you are right, you're required to create the object yourself because by default, DRF cannot create nested objects for you. That is exactly what I do by letting the nested serializer create it and since I already have the nested object(not raw json data), I can now call serializer create to handle the creation of the parent object with all nested objects in place. It's also possible to manually create it here but you will have to have nested `for` for each layer of nested objects. That isn't a very nice code when you have 3 layers and above

Comment: @c6754 and to be precise, DRF doesn't require that you manually create the objects using the model, rather it requires that you override the create method and handle the creation. Note how the create method of each serializer has been overridden to allow the creation of nested objects? except for `SmokerSerializer` of course since it doesn't have any nested object

Comment: Yes I understand, I'm saying that in the [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writing-create-methods-for-nested-representations), where they discuss the `create` function for the writable nested model they just call Object.create and they don't use the serializer. The data has already been validated by the, e.g. `SmokerSerializer` at that point (once we are in `create`).

Comment: Couldn't edit my old comment, I see now that you're right and I bet that is his issue.

Comment: @c6754 One thing you should know is that there's never just one way of doing things and examples are usually too simple compared to real-life tasks. For one level of nesting that works well.  Now when it comes to this particular case, if you try to create the switch using Switch.objects.create() in survey serializer, you will get the exact same error because the switch data contains smoker data (in json!) but Switch.objects.create() expects a smoker object not some json data. Which means you need create smoker before creating switch. Again, you can do all that in surveryserialier with for loop

Comment: @c6754 glad you finally understood. I hope the OP understands too

Comment: Ya I was fixated on just the first level with the `Switch` and `Smoker` relationship.

Comment: @AndrehAbboud If you don't want to use the code I provided, I've already given enough explanations in the comments that you should know what the problem in your code is and how it can be solved. So you can go ahead and solve it however you see fit. Goodluck!

Comment: i put the code you suggest but it is giving the switch:null just tell me what to do next i don't understand what to do i am beginner in drf

Comment: @AndrehAbboud you're saying you used the code exactly and you don't get any errors but the switch is null?? that can't be. It should throw an error if it can't successfully assign switch, so post the error here and I can check what the issue is

Answer (score 0):

In `SwitchSerializer` you defined the `create` function as a method of the inner `Meta` class and not as a member of `SwitchSerializer` class. Try this

```
class SwitchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    smoker = SmokerSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Switch
        fields = '__all__'
    def create(self, validated_data):
       smoker_data = validated_data.pop('smoker', None)
       if smoker_data:
           smoker = Smoker.objects.create(**smoker_data)
           validated_data['smoker'] = smoker
       return Switch.objects.create(**validated_data)
```